# How to enable TLS for an AWS S3 endpoint with a self-controlled certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

We have an IoT device that uploads data to an AWS S3 endpoint. To enable TLS (secure HTTPS transfer), it is necessary to add the S3 endpoint certificate to the IoT device SD card.

This works fine if we add the URL (`https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname`) in the browser, click the lock icon and export the root CA certificate for our SD card. However, Amazon may decide to change this over time without notice - and we're unable to add more than 1 certificate to the IoT SD card.

To solve this, we've been looking at options for enabling TLS on our S3 endpoint with a certificate that we control - so that it will not change unless we decide to do so. However, we're unsure what is the right solution for this.

We've looked at AWS CloudFront, adding a custom domain to our endpoint and adding a certificate. But we're unsure if this will work - and if it's the best solution. Any inputs are welcome.

Comment: cloudfront with custom domain is the way to do this. do the certificate stuff through certificate manager. it's really easy.

Comment: Thanks - one thing we're trying to understand: Is there any way to achieve this without having to register a custom domain? We would be fine with using the original "raw" domain name, i.e. `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname`, but I'm not sure if this is doable with the CloudFront solution (or any)?

Comment: could use an api gateway as an s3 proxy. that's about it all I can think of.

Comment: may i know why you are trying to do this without a custom domain for this purpose?

Comment: Our ideal scenario would be to just use the existing S3 REST endpoint with https in front - but with a "fixed" certificate. We need to be able to be 100% sure that the root certificate does not change without warning - otherwise the IoT device will go offline and be unreachable if TLS is enabled after the certificate changes. By far, the easiest way would be if it was possible to just use the existing default AWS certificate and be warned in advanced of a change. Or, if a custom certificate could be loaded natively foran S3 bucket. The CloudFront/custom domain seems very convoluted for this.

Comment: You can't create your own "custom certificate" for a domain name that you don't own, so you can't apply your own certificate to an S3 bucket URL. Amazon is not going to let you create a certificate for the `s3.amazonaws.com` domain. By far the best way to gain control over the SSL certificate used by your S3 bucket is to place your own custom domain in front of that bucket via something like CloudFront.

Comment: It sounds as if you might be referring to issuing either a self-signed certificate or one from your own private CA, rather than one from a publicly trusted certificate authority.  Is that right?  If so, CloudFront -- which I would ordinarily endorse without hesitation -- may not be viable, since the [rules for front-side certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements) explicitly say that self-signed certificates aren't allowed and strongly imply that certs from private CAs aren't allowed either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be assured that AWS would provide plenty of advance notice on a CA root cert change for a key service endpoint like s3.amazonaws.com. That type of change would have significant maintenance impact on all consumers of that endpoint. They simply cannot change the CA root certificate without proper notice to customers.

So the easiest solution for this use case is to use the standard AWS endpoint, and handle any upgrades to the CA cert as a maintenance task on the device, when the CA root is replaced in the future.

The custom domain + cloudfront is the valid solution for using your own SSL cert on your own domain. But note that it also will have a CA root cert that would be subject to a potential future root cert update - same as the default endpoint. So you really do not gain any more independence on CA changes there. For this reason, a Cloud Front solution would just add complexity, with no real advantage to your use case. If however you really want to run your own private CA and control the expiration date of your own root CA certificate, you could use the AWS Certificate Manager Private Certificate Authority. See https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/

FYI the root CA certificate on the S3 endpoint expires in 5  year 4 months. It uses the DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2 cert issued by Baltimore CyberTrust Root and uses good strong encryption eg key length and signature algorithm. I would not expect any reason AWS would replace that cert until it's expiration date.

See https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=s3.amazonaws.com for SSL analysis of the AWS S3 certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We fully agree that what you propose would be the simplest solution - however, we've been unable to find anywhere where we can subscribe to AWS providing information on pending changes to the root CA certificate for their S3 endpoint. If we were able to get such a subscription, it would by far be the simplest case. We also would not expect the root CA to change prior to the expiration date - but we just had this exact thing happen with an Azure endpoint used for another of our IoT devices. AWS also stated on their forums that the root CA may change without notice.

Comment: See for example this old forum link where somebody asks for early warning if there's a root certificate change: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=77058

Comment: @mfcss If you need absolute certainty on CA root changes, then the AWS Private CA would work for you. Down side is price at $400 usd per month.